# QtNetwork module not found in qml/quick in qt 6.5.2

Tags: qt6, qtnetwork

I am using debian 12 and qt 6.5.2. Qt installed in external HDD inside my laptop. I want to use qtnetwork module in qml file. So, I have added network in .pro and it works fine(successfully included in cpp header file without any error) but problem when try to include in qml file.Give this `eror message: "QML module not found(QtNetwork)"`. Here is my code:

QML File:

import QtQuick 2.15
import Qt.Nework //problem arise here
import QtQuick.Controls

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    height: parent
    width: parent

    // properties
    property string targetAddress: "127.0.0.1"
    property int startPort: 1
    property int endPort: 65535


}
```

.pro file
QT       += core gui network quick quickcontrols2 quickwidgets qml

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    portscanner.cpp

HEADERS += \
    portscanner.h

FORMS += \
    portscanner.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc

DISTFILES +=
`
**main.cpp file**

`#include "portscanner.h"
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts);
    QQuickWindow::setGraphicsApi(QSGRendererInterface::OpenGLRhi);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    PortScanner w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

and implementation file
#include "portscanner.h"
#include "ui_portscanner.h"

```
PortScanner::PortScanner(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::PortScanner)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // show qml file
    ui->qml_viewer->setSource (QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/SuperFastDownloadManagerGui.qml")));
}

PortScanner::~PortScanner()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I found this https://forum.qt.io/topic/143956/module-qtnetwork-is-not-installed but not work.